# Calling Wordpress functions with Ajax from client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress site with WooCommerce and I am also making a HTML5 app for my little store. My desire is to call Wordpress functions (such as research) through Ajax from my HTML5 app, and get the results WITH THE IMAGES of profucts in my store. I fetched on Google about it, but nothing really interesting...

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check [this codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? Even though it says plugins, it applies to themes too. Just put the server-side code in your functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to make sure you can get the WordPress `admin-ajax.php` URL dynamically (never hardcoded, unless your *HTML5 app* is not part of the WordPress store). To do so, add this to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function so46065926_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'so46065926-ajax', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/js/ajax.js' ), array( 'jquery' ) );

    // Make the Ajax URL available in your ajax.js
    wp_localize_script( 'so46065926-ajax', 'so46065926', array(
        'ajaxURL' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so46065926_scripts' );
```

Then you can create a function that gets the info you need. You can use WooCommerce functions here, because you're on your `functions.php`

```
function so46065926_research() {
    $form_data = $_POST['formData']; // The parameter you sent in your Ajax request.

    /**
     * Anything you echo here, will be returned to your Ajax.
     * For instance, a template part, and that template part
     * can contain the product image.
     */
    get_template_part( 'template-part/content', 'product-research' );

    wp_die(); // Don't forget to add this line, otherwise you'll get 0 at the end of your response.
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_research',        'so46065926_research' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_research', 'so46065926_research' );
```

Then, you're ready to build up your client side script. It could be something like:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'submit', '.research-form', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = jQuery( this ).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: so46065926.ajaxURL,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            action: 'research', // Remember the 'wp_ajax_research' above? This is the wp_ajax_{research} part
            formData: formData,
        }
    } )
    .done( function( data ) {
        jQuery( '.my-ajax-div' ).html( data );
    } )
    .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { // HTTP Error
        console.error( errorThrown );
    } );
} );
```

Keep in mind this is just the basis for your goal, there are tons of references out there that could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !